# Nuance Mobile always returns zero results if I enable Grammar Recognition Mode

Tags: android, ios, speech-recognition, context-free-grammar, speech-to-text

I have an iOS and an Android app that do Speech to Text recognition using Nuance Mobile SDK. Both apps work perfectly when using a Nuance sandbox appID.
However, when if I upload a phrase file, the Nuance server always returns zero results, as I can verify in the "didFinishWithResults" methods on both android and ios.
This is the phrase file I upload as a custom vocabulary to Nuance:

```
<phrases>
 <phrase>two on to</phrase>
 <phrase>bet 1 3 for</phrase>
 <phrase>...and some other phrases.</phrase>
</phrases>
```

My Nuance custom dictionary is set to:

```
Topic:WebSearch
Grammar recognition mode: YES (<== Apps work perfectly when set to NO)
Vocabulary Weight: 90
```

Nuance's documentation claims that:

*It is important to note that custom vocabularies are different than the constrained speech
recognition grammars many developers are familiar with. Using constrained grammars results in
high accuracy of words that are in the grammar and low (or no) recognition of words or phrases
that are not in the grammar. With custom vocabularies our large language models are still used
and the vocabulary simply adjusts the recognition probabilities of that large model. As a result,
using a vocabulary will not change your results as much as a conventional grammar would. For
example, you can expect to still get word results that are not in the vocabulary or “out of
grammar.” The grammar recognition mode feature makes the vocabulary act much more like a
traditional recognition grammar but as we are still using the underlying language model even
then you may get “out of grammar” results.*

.....So my question is, What am I doing wrong to always get zero results from Nuance ASR when the custom vocabulary's grammar recognition mode is set to YES?

Nuance's customer support is totally useless, they probably outsource a bunch of people with just an FAQ in hand that have no idea about anything.
I hope somebody can help me out on this one.